# What is the purpose of @ in regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

For example:

```
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $user);
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $user);
```

Why before and after regex for letters we have: @ ?
What is the purpose of this symbol put it in this way?

Comment: It's an alternative [regex delimiter](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is a delimiter.  You can use almost anything so long as it doesn't appear in the pattern, or it must be escaped.  This is equivalent with `/` delimiter:

```
$uppercase = preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $user);
```

For filepaths for example, `/` would be troublesome as you would have to escape it:

```
'/something\/test\/and\/other\/stuff\/'
```

To use `@` as a delimiter in an email regex you would need (just an example):

```
'@me\@example\.com@'
```

Comment: Yep. I prefer `@` because it's very easy to see and takes up a lot of space.